# XCode- Need Help With Errors (Expected ; and Expected Statement)

Tags: xcode

.m coding:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathMusic2" ofType:@"wav"];
    self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]
    autorelease];  //error: expected ';' before 'autorelease' and // error: expected statement before ']' token
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;

   }
```

related warnings:

> warning: property 'theAudio' requires
>   method '-theAudio' to be defined - use
>   @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation
>
> warning: property 'theAudio' requires
>   the method 'setTheAudio:' to be
>   defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or
>   provide a method implementation

tell me if you need .h coding. But there are no errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two errors are because you are missing an opening `[` in the previous line:

```
self.theAudio = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL] autorelease];
```

The warnings are because you forgot `@synthesize theAudio;` in your @implementation (or forgot to write custom getter and setter methods). At runtime, you'll get an unknown selector exception if you don't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It was me in the previous question, my code was erroneous, this should correct it:

```
self.theAudio = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL] autorelease];
```

To this error:

> warning: property 'theAudio' requires
>   method '-theAudio' to be defined - use
>   @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation

Do you know what a property is? If not, look at [this short tutorial](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-properties-setters-and-dot-syntax.html). I actually provided the code in your previous question, but you have to know where to put it.

Comment: A property is something declared in your `@interface` block using the `@property` keyword. It's basically a bit of syntactic sugar so you can use syntax like `object.theAudio` and `object.theAudio = value` instead of `[object theAudio]` and `[object setTheAudio:value]`.