# expected identifer or "(" Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am incredibly new to xcode and im making an app for a school project. I am working on a background music code to play/pause on the same button (found the code but modified it some). I've been able to clear up the other errors but I don't know what to do about this... expected identifier or "("

```
@implementation settingscontroller2

-(void) btnAction:(UIButton*)button{
button.selected = !button.selected;}

{ //expected Identifier or "("


if (button.selected){

    // Play
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"app" ofType:@"mp3"];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [theAudio play];
}

else (!button.selected){

    // Pause
    [theAudio pause];
    return.nil
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765026/xcode-need-help-with-errors-expected-and-expected-statement

Comment: You put a curly brace after `button.selected = !button.selected;`. Remove it and you should be good to go. Also `return.nil` isn't valid syntax, remove it since it's a void method and doesn't need return at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once check this one,

```
-(void) btnAction:(UIButton*)button{
    button.selected = !button.selected;


    if (button.selected){

        // Play
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"app" ofType:@"mp3"];
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        theAudio.delegate = self;
        theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [theAudio play];
    }

    else if(!button.selected){//here also one problem in your code.

        // Pause
        [theAudio pause];
        //return.nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
button.selected = !button.selected;}
```

The "}" is too much as the following "{".

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) btnAction:(UIButton*)button{
    button.selected = !button.selected;}

{ //expected Identifier or "("
```

You've got two method bodies here. It looks like you should probably remove the first `}` and the next `{`, and maybe reformat a bit, so that you have:

```
-(void) btnAction:(UIButton*)button
{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    if (button.selected){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the second last line with return;

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `}` at the end of

```
button.selected = !button.selected;
```

and the line that gives you error.